# with() returns null when I give parameters to get()

Tags: php, laravel

I have two classes, `BedRequest` and `RequestThing`:

```
class BedRequest extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'bed_request';

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function requests()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(RequestThing::class, 'request_id');
    }
}

class RequestThing extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'requests';

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function bedRequests()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(BedRequest::class);
    }
}
```

I am trying to get the following output format, where `post_status` and `created_at` are the fields of `BedRequest` and `requests` key holds the data fetched in relationship with `RequestThing`:

```
[
     {
            "post_status": 0,
            "created_at": "2021-05-03T08:29:37.000000Z",
            "requests": {
                "id": 128,
                "name": "John Doe",
                "age": "52",
                "gender": "male",
                "contact": "9101235456",
                "address": "Kentucky",
                "urgency": "urgent",
                "reason": "Some reason",
                "filler_name": "Mahim",
                "filler_contact": "9160236160",
                "filler_address": "Bali",
                "filler_relation": "others",
                "created_at": "2021-05-03T08:29:37.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-05-03T09:47:17.000000Z"
            }
        }
   ]
```

So, I wrote the following code in my controller:

```
public function bedRequest()
    {    
        $bedRequests = BedRequest::where(['approved' => 1, 'post_status' => 0])->with('requests')->get(['post_status', 'created_at']);
        return $bedRequests;
    }
```

But when I did that, the response I got was:

```
[
    {
        "post_status": 0,
        "created_at": "2021-05-03T08:29:37.000000Z",
        "requests": null
    }
]
```

The `requests` key gives `null` value. However, if I do the following (i.e. remove the parameters from `get()`, the `requests` key gets populated with data and I receive the whole data of `BedRequest` as well. But, I just need `post_status` and `created_at` from `BedRequest` and `requests` that holds the data from `RequestThing`.

Could anyone please suggest a solution?

Comment: Can you also share your desired output? Is it like this : `[{"post_status": 0,"created_at": "2021-05-03T08:29:37.000000Z"}]`

Comment: I have mentioned the desired output in the question. Please refer to the paragraph that says, "I am trying to get the following output format..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this:

```
$bedRequests = BedRequest::where(['approved' => 1, 'post_status' => 0])->with('requests')->get(['post_status', 'created_at', 'bedRequest_id']);
```

> You are getting null for requests and it could be because you have
> some specific fields and most probably you didn't select the
> foreing_key from the BedRequest table that creates the relationship
> with requests, so if your bedRequests table contains the foreign_key
> (probably request_id) of requests table then you have to select that
> foreign_key from the bedRequests table too. So, just add that
> foreign_key/bedRequest_id in the get() parameters. Without the
> relation builder key (FK) the requests won't be loaded.

Comment: This solved my problem. Although the response contains an extra field `request_id`, it works for me. Thank you!